# How to create random rooms in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently doing a chat app using angular js. And i came to the point where someone could create a new room. But of course like always i faced a problem, This one being a big one where i didn't understand how to attack it.

I need to create multiple rooms using random hashes like `chattapp.com/somerandomhashroom` I seriously am clueless on how to attack that problem.

[Here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/chattapp) is my cloud 9(Where i work on actual project), and [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ToWpQCw6GaKYkUegFjMi?p=preview) is the plunker i created. So i really need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a random string like so:

```
function getRandomString(length) {
    var string = "";
    var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        string += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: And how do i make the hashes. Like how do i implement them to my config. I gtg now please give me an anwser. Thankyou SOO MUch for your time and help